# Access issues with google forms and sheets

Tags: google-forms

I have created Two google forms which a bunch of people submit too, currently these are both linked to a google sheets workbook. Where I have two other collaborators working with this and managing it. But to gain access to the images that have been uploaded they need to request access by myself.

We are running on the free version of google forms, drive etc. Is there a way they can just open the google drive image without having to request access?